# how to have block show up on specific pages AND specific content types

Tags: blocks

I want to be able to have a particular menu block show up on specific pages, as well as on specific content type pages. My content type pages don't start with /node, so I can't simply say

```
pagename
/node/*
```

in the block settings. (I am trying to do this from the UI. If thats not possible, then please tell me what the best way to do this in code is.)

Answer (score 1):

The [Context](https://drupal.org/project/context) module makes advanced block placement very easy in the ui. In your case you would:

1. Download Context and enable Context and Context UI,
2. go to admin/structure/context,
3. click add,
4. give your context a Name in machine name format (no spaces, use lowercase and underscores) ie. my_context
5. Under "Conditions" add a condition of "Node Type"
6. Select your Content Types
7. Add another condition, of "Path"
8. Enter the specific paths that you would like the block to appear on, one path per line
9. Add a "Reaction" of type Block
10. Check your block or blocks off to the right and click the "+ Add" button in the region that you would like to place the block.